# Android Camera: Can not change flash mode from torch to other mode

Tags: android, android-camera

In android L, I am trying to set camera flash mode to `TORCH` and it works fine but I can  not change it back to flash mode `AUTO` or flash mode `ON`. I can only come back to flash mode `OFF`. I tried popular camera apps like camera360, even they failed doing that. 
Is this a bug in android L or is it compulsory to use new `CAMERA2` api's?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Android Lollipop version.
This is how I solved it

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters =  mCamera.getParameters();
 parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
 mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
 parameters.setFlashMode(yourFlashMode);
 mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Don't forget to check if flash mode is supported by calling `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes()`

Comment: thought I had it working, but still i think it's a bug with lollipop.  For some reason it won't honor flash after taking some pictures.   I noticed Instagram always defaults to no flash every time you take a picture too.

Comment: @reidisaki I find the `Samsung Note4` has the same problem.